# How can I get inverted index?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'new using Spark. 
How can I get inverted index for csv file by using Spark? I have csv file

```
df.show()
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|      id|               title|                tags|closeddate|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|48702270|                null|                null|      null|
|48702455|                null|                null|      null|
|48702469|                null|                null|      null|
|48704166|                null|                null|      null|
|48704172|                null|                null|      null|
|48704243|Transfer files fr...|<java><android><f...|      null|
|48704263|for each loops as...|<java><java-8><mu...|      null|
```

How can I get the inverted index that shows top tags as an example?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the tags column to array, like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def read_tags_raw(tags_string): 
    return tags_string.strip('>').strip('<').split('><') if tags_string else []

read_tags = udf(read_tags_raw, ArrayType(StringType()))
df_valid_tags = df.withColumn('tags', read_tags('tags'))
```

Then you call explode and group by tag to create inverted index:

```
df_valid_tags.select(explode('tags').alias('tag'), 'id') \
    .groupBy('tag').agg(collect_list('id').alias('ids'))
```

Good luck working with SO database ;-)